# passing data from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this type of code. From js I successfully pass object. After echo of $pricecnt. I can't see it. I did something wrong please help me and I'm a begginer and maybe I did simple mistake.

> Probably the problematic part connected with pricecnt.

```
 <?php 

if (isset($_POST['taxtypeid'])) {
  $pricecnt = isset($_POST['pricecnt']);
  echo $pricecnt; // I don't see it
  $taxsumid = $_POST['taxtypeid'];
  $taxsum = json_decode($taxsumid); 
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO invoce_tax_applay (harkumId, byPriceOrCnt, totalSum, insertVersionId) VALUES (:harkumId, :byPriceOrCnt, :totalSum, :insertVersionId)";
    $stmt1 = $pdo1->prepare($sql1);

  foreach ($taxsum as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."-->".$value.":";
     $stmt1->execute([
      'harkumId' => $key,
      'byPriceOrCnt' => $pricecnt,
      'totalSum' => $value,
      'insertVersionId' => ''

    ]);
  }

?>

<script>
var pricecnt = document.getElementById("opt_ion").value;
function confirm2(){
let taxsum = new Object();
let tax = document.getElementById("taxingtype").value;
let sum = parseInt(document.getElementById("gumar").value);
taxsum[tax] = sum;
var taxtypeid = JSON.stringify(taxsum);
$.ajax({
    url: 'product_inputs_inc.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {taxtypeid: taxtypeid; pricecnt: pricecnt},
    success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    }
});
}   
</script>
```

Comment: Hi you have typo here `$POST['pricecnt']` should be `$_POST['pricecnt']`

Comment: Thank u for that mention. But it isn't help.

Comment: where is the part where these value are actually set in html? did you verify using browser inspect that data is actually been posted?

Comment: thank u very much, I just realized mistake

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean value which will not have any output using `echo`

Comment: if it is true  $pricecnt = 1 else $pricecnt=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw my mistake

wrong

> data: {taxtypeid: taxtypeid; pricecnt: pricecnt},

right

```
data: {taxtypeid: taxtypeid, pricecnt: pricecnt},
```